# How to send sms messages using twilio and windows scheduler?

Tags: php, sms, twilio, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to schedule when I send sms messages using Twilio. I currently can  schedule when to run php scripts using Windows Scheduler, however, whenever I try to send messages using twilio, the script doesn't execute.

PHP script that sends sms text message via using twilio

```
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
include '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    '+19894837813',
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => '+19823837823',
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => 'Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!'
    )
);

?>
```

VB script that references batch file

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\xampp\htdocs\Twilio\php\script.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Batch file that calles php script

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\Twilio\php\index.php"
```

Comment: If that SID and token are your real ones you'll want to go change them immediately.

Comment: What is there a VB script in the mix at all. Just call PHP directly from the scheduler. Don't even need a batch file.